# FormData: Por que o URL aparece indefinida?

Tags: formdata

A ideia é pegar o *value* do **input[name="caminho"]** e usá-lo como o valor de **url** do metódo AJAX. Porém o meu console está mostrando que esse valor está *Undefined*.

Não consegui descobrir o motivo ainda.

Meu HTML:

```html
<a class="rtrn-conteudo" objeto="form_objeto">Logout</a>
<form id="form_objeto">
 <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="logout"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="caminho" value="meu/caminho/aqui.nesse.formato"/>
</form>
```

Meu JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body")
    .on("click", ".rtrn-conteudo", function(event) {

      var objeto = new FormData(document.querySelector("#" + $(this).attr("objeto")));

      $.ajax({
        url: objeto["caminho"], //Detalhe: se eu usar "meu/caminho/aqui.nesse.formato" escrito direto, funciona.
        data: objeto,
        type: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(retornoDados) {
          $("body").html(retornoDados);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar o valor no `formData` use o `get`

```
url: objeto.get("caminho")
```

Pode ver mais sobre nessa [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get)

Para preencher o `formData` você também pode fazer assim:

```
var objeto = new FormData(document.getElementById('form_objeto'));
```

Desta forma você não precisaria ter um atributo "objeto" com o id do `form`